# Debugging custom Script Tool Error 000732?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, error-000732

I am having a problem when importing a script into a custom script tool. I am not the strongest person with Python, but I have an existing script tool which was created by someone who does not work here any more. I believe I know where the error is within the script, just not sure how to fix it. Once I import the script and attempt to run the tool I receive "error 000732 - Template shapefile does not exist"

Any thoughts or ideas?

I am led to think the problem lies with this section of code:

```
# get a path to the template shapefile
tmplShp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),
                       '..',
                       'data',
                       'raster_index_tmpl.shp'))
```

Full code listed below

```
 #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Description:
#   Generate footprints for all raster products within a directory. Can
#   optionally perform a recursive traverse to find all rasters within the
#   tree.
#
#   Produces a single shapefile output with attributes to identify each raster
#   dataset found.
#
# ArcGIS Version: 10.0
# Python Version: 2.6
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import arcpy
import datetime
import os
import sys


def message(msg, severity=0):
    """Notify the user of some event with a message.

    Arcpy does not print messages to command line, and print statements
    do not appear within the Arc runtime. This method can act as a global
    notification system for both environments.
    """
    # print a message to the command line
    print msg

    # notify the user within the arc environment
    # splits a message on \n, making a notification for each line in a
    # multiline string
    try:
        for string in msg.split('\n'):
            # add message under appropriate severity
            if severity == 0:
                arcpy.AddMessage(string)
            elif severity == 1:
                arcpy.AddWarning(string)
            elif severity == 2:
                arcpy.AddError(string)
    except:
        # ignore errors
        pass

def listRasters(rasterTypes = "ALL"):
    """Generate a list of rasters found within a workspace."""

    # keep a list of all files for all types
    foundFiles = []

    if rasterTypes == "ALL":
        # just gather all file types
        foundFiles = arcpy.ListRasters("*", rasterTypes)
    else:
        # arcpy will not let us specify multiple file types to search for, so
        # we replicate that ability by appending the file lists for each
        # specified file type.
        fileTypes = rasterTypes.split(';')
        for fileType in fileTypes:
            foundFiles.extend(arcpy.ListRasters("*", fileType))

    # return all discovered files
    return foundFiles

def processRasterList(shapefile, rasterList):
    """Process a list of rasters into coordinates and attributes."""
    # make sure there is some data to be processed
    # if no data is found, notify the user and move on
    if not len(rasterList):
        message("No rasters found.")
        return

    # notify the user work is starting
    message("Processing %d rasters." % len(rasterList))
    arcpy.SetProgressor("step",
                        "Processing rasters...",
                        0,
                        len(rasterList))

    # keep track of if we find any projected data
    projDataFound = False
    for rasterStr in rasterList:
        # inform the user which raster is being processed
        arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Processing %s" % rasterStr)

        # Wrap the whole thing in a try block to catch possible problems
        # Problems are ignored, and the user is notified that a raster was
        # not processed.
        try:
            # make a raster object
            raster = arcpy.Raster(rasterStr)
        except:
            message("Processing raster failed: %s" % rasterStr, 1)
            message(arcpy.GetMessages(2), 1)
            # abondon this raster and move on
            continue

        # notify the user if projected data is found (prefer geographic)
        if raster.spatialReference.type == "Unknown":
            projDataFound = True
        if raster.spatialReference.name!="Unknown":
            # generate an array to hold each corner of the raster
            coords = arcpy.Array()

            # add each corner of the raster to the array
            coords.add(raster.extent.lowerLeft)
            coords.add(raster.extent.upperLeft)
            coords.add(raster.extent.upperRight)
            coords.add(raster.extent.lowerRight)
            # Polygons require the start coordinate to match the end coordinate
            coords.add(raster.extent.lowerLeft)

            # make a polygon from the points array
            rasterPolygon = arcpy.Polygon(coords, raster.spatialReference)

            try:
                # use an insert cursor to create new records for this raster
                fcRows = arcpy.InsertCursor(shapefile, )
                # make a new row
                row = fcRows.newRow()
                # set all the attributes
                row.shape = rasterPolygon
                row.path = raster.path
                row.filename = raster.name
                row.type = raster.format
                row.process_d = str(datetime.date.today())
                row.num_rows = raster.height
                row.num_cols = raster.width
                row.xmin = raster.extent.XMin
                row.xmax = raster.extent.XMax
                row.ymin = raster.extent.YMin
                row.ymax = raster.extent.YMax
                row.Projection = raster.spatialReference.name
                row.datum = raster.spatialReference.spheroidName
                row.epsg_code = raster.spatialReference.factoryCode
                row.num_bands = raster.bandCount
                row.pixelw = raster.meanCellWidth
                row.pixelh = raster.meanCellHeight
                row.bit_depth = int(raster.pixelType[1:])
                row.comptype = raster.compressionType

                # insert the row into the featureclass
                fcRows.insertRow(row)

                # free up some memory
                del row
                del fcRows
                del coords

            except:
                message("Cataloging raster failed: %s" % rasterStr, 1)
                message(arcpy.GetMessages(2), 1)

            # update the progress bar position
            arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()

    # notify the user if any unprojected data was found
    if projDataFound:
        message("Unprojected data found. Check outputs.", 1)
    # reset the progress bar to normal
    arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Looking for rasters...")
    arcpy.ResetProgressor()

def create_featureclass(fcPath, inMemory=False):
    """Create a shapefile to store all the data that is collected from a raster
    list. Also adds all fields required for metadata about each raster.

    """
    # split the path into its component parts
    (dirName, fileName) = os.path.split(fcPath)
    # make all outputs WGS84 Geographic
    spatialReference = os.path.join(arcpy.GetInstallInfo()["InstallDir"],
                             r"Coordinate Systems\Geographic Coordinate Systems\World\WGS 1984.prj")
    # get a path to the template shapefile
    tmplShp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),
                           '..',
                           'data',
                           'raster_index_tmpl.shp'))
    # check if creating feature in memory
    if inMemory == "true":
        dirName = "in_memory"
        fileName = "memoryindex"

    # create the featureclass
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(dirName,
                                        fileName,
                                        "POLYGON",
                                        tmplShp,
                                        "DISABLED",
                                        "DISABLED",
                                        spatialReference)

    return os.path.join(dirName, fileName)

## fields come from the template shapefile, this is just for reference
##    # add appropriate fields to the featureclass
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'Path', 'TEXT', 254)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'Filename', 'TEXT', 254)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'Type', 'TEXT', 16)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'Process_D', 'DATE')
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'NUM_Rows', 'LONG')
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'NUM_Cols', 'LONG')
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'XMin', 'FLOAT', 15, 10)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'XMax', 'FLOAT', 15, 10)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'YMin', 'FLOAT', 15, 10)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'YMax', 'FLOAT', 15, 10)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'Projection', 'TEXT', 50)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'Datum', 'TEXT', 50)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'EPSG_Code', 'TEXT', 6)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'NUM_Bands', 'SHORT')
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'PixelW', 'FLOAT', 15, 10)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'PixelH', 'FLOAT', 15, 10)
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'BIT_DEPTH', 'SHORT')
##    arcpy.AddField_management(fcPath, 'Compression', 'TEXT', 20)


def index_rasters(inputWorkspace, outputFeatureClass, processRecursive,
                  inMemoryProcessing, fileTypes = ""):
    """Process all rasters within a given directory."""
    # notify if using in memory processing
    if inMemoryProcessing == "true":
        message("Using in memory processing")

    # support the ability to index multiple directories at the same time, either
    # as recursive or not.
    inputWorkspaces = inputWorkspace.split(';')
    for inWS in inputWorkspaces:
        # arc wraps directories in quotes for fun
        inWS = inWS.replace("'", "")
        # set the workspace to be the base directory from the user
        arcpy.env.workspace = inWS

        # if the user doesn't want to process only certain files, set "ALL"
        if fileTypes == "":
            fileTypes = "ALL"

        try:
            # create a featureclass to hold all raster metadata
            if len(inputWorkspaces) == 1 or not arcpy.Exists(outputFeatureClass):
                featureData = create_featureclass(outputFeatureClass,
                                                  inMemoryProcessing)

            # Determine if recursive. No need to walk if not doing a recursive
            # list.
            if processRecursive == 'false':
                message("Gathering raster list from %s" % arcpy.env.workspace)
                rasterList = listRasters(fileTypes)
                processRasterList(featureData, rasterList)
            else:
                message("Recursive processing started.")
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inWS):
                    # have to do this once for the top level folder
                    arcpy.env.workspace = root
                    message("Gathering raster list from %s" % arcpy.env.workspace)
                    rasterList = listRasters(fileTypes)
                    processRasterList(featureData, rasterList)
##                    for subdir in dirs:
##                        arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(root, subdir)
##                        message("Gathering raster list from %s" % arcpy.env.workspace)
##                        rasterList = listRasters(fileTypes)
##                        processRasterList(outputFeatureClass, rasterList)

            if inMemoryProcessing == "true":
                # if processing was done in memory, write items to disk
                arcpy.Merge_management(featureData, outputFeatureClass)
                # delete the in memory feature class
                arcpy.Delete_management(featureData)

        except arcpy.ExecuteError:
            print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
            arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
        except Exception as e:
            print e.args[0]
            arcpy.AddError(e.args[0])

# Test how the script is running. This allows it to run from multiple
# environments, or to be included as a module into another script without
# destroying environments.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # gather all arguments that have been passed in
    argv = tuple(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(i)
                 for i in xrange(arcpy.GetArgumentCount()))
    index_rasters(*argv)
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the template does exists at the path of tmplShp?

Answer (score 2):

The file defined in tmplShp doesn't exist.

Assuming your script is in C:\script, the file it is looking for is C:\data\raster_index_tmpl.shp

So, whatever directory your script is in, go up one, find the data folder, and make sure there is a shapefile called raster_index_tmpl.shp present.

Comment: Or provide the *full* path to raster_index_tmpl.shp in the function (eg: c:\\some\\path\\raster_index_tmpl.shp)